# Unable to create project for custom vision image classification using Java SDK

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-java-sdk, microsoft-custom-vision

I am unable to create the project for the custom vision image classification using Java SDK. It is giving an error in the following line in the main method of CustomVisionQuickstart.java
Project project = createProject(trainClient);

I am following the Java SDK quickstart guide for custom vision

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/quickstarts/image-classification?tabs=visual-studio&pivots=programming-language-java#prerequisites

Comment: [Status code 404, {"error":{"code":"404","message": "Resource not found"}}](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/47698) and [Cognitive Services - Computer Vision - Analize Image always returns error 404](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/21253)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cognitive Services Custom Vision SDK NotFound Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55959026/cognitive-services-custom-vision-sdk-notfound-error)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following the code block used in the current scenario:

```
CustomVisionQuickstart.java 
Project project = createProject(trainClient);
```

**Replace the above code block with the below code block**

```
Trainings trainings = client.trainings();
Project project = trainings.createProject().withName("Dog Breeds").execute();
```

This will solve the error.

For complete project creation and implementation in Java. Checkout the [link](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-build-an-ml-custom-image-classifier-in-java)

Document Credits: [Ruth Yakubu](https://dzone.com/users/3255454/ruyakubu.html)